# linqtotwitter finding more than 100 searches

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm trying to find all the possible entries on twitter for a particular keyword, but using the code below only the fist 100 are returned. The search returns null on the second iteration. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public async void SearchForTweets()
    {
        const int maxNumberToFind = 100;
        const string whatToFind = "iphone";

        ulong lastId = 0;
        var total = 0;
        int count;
        do
        {
            var id = lastId;

            // Get the first 100 records, or the first 100 whose ID is less than the previous set
            var searchResponse =
                await
                    (from search in _twitterCtx.Search
                     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                           search.Query == whatToFind &&
                           search.Count == maxNumberToFind &&
                           (id == 0 || search.MaxID < id)
                     select search)
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            // Only if we find something
            if (searchResponse != null && searchResponse.Statuses != null)
            {
                // Out put each tweet found
                searchResponse.Statuses.ForEach(tweet =>
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "{4} ID: {3} Created: {2} User: {0}, Tweet: {1}",
                        tweet.User.ScreenNameResponse,
                        tweet.Text,
                        tweet.CreatedAt,
                        tweet.StatusID,
                        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

                // Take a note of how many we found, and keep a running total
                count = searchResponse.Statuses.Count;
                total += count;

                // What is the ID of the oldest found (Used to limit the next search)
                lastId = searchResponse.Statuses.Min(x => x.StatusID);
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        } while (count == maxNumberToFind); // Until we find less than 100
        Console.Out.WriteLine("total = {0}", total);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get All Tweets on Hashtag using LinqToTwitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943598/how-to-get-all-tweets-on-hashtag-using-linqtotwitter)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it,

```
search.MaxID < id
```

needs to be

```
search.MaxID == id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full function

```
public static List<Status> search(string searchTerms, int maxPagination)
{
    var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(authorizer);
    List<Status> searchResults = new List<Status>();
    int maxNumberToFind = 100;
    int pagination = 0;
    ulong lastId = 0;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        var id = lastId;
        var tweets = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(
                        from tweet in twitterCtx.Search
                        where tweet.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                            tweet.Query == searchTerms &&
                            tweet.Count == maxNumberToFind && (tweet.MaxID == id)
                        select tweet);

        searchResults.AddRange(tweets.Statuses.ToList());
        lastId = tweets.Statuses.Min(x => x.StatusID); // What is the ID of the oldest found (Used to get the next pagination(results)
        pagination++;

        count = (pagination > maxPagination) ? 0 : tweets.Count; // Limit amount of search results
    } while (count == maxNumberToFind);

    return searchResults;
}
```